# ASP net core MVC Call diferent actions under 1 form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my this in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Save(int IdentifikaceZ, ReklamaceModel model)
        {
            _db.Add(model);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("MyMainView");
        }
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyMainView", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        ....
        <input id="Insert" name="Insert" value="Insert" type="submit">
        <input id="Edit" name="Edit" value="Edit" type="submit">
    }
```

What I need is to Save/Edit info inside Form but I dont know how to tell server to decide which to do. So when I click button A or button B it does same thing. I need it to do seperate things but with same elemetns (elements inside form) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons are named, and the way named buttons work is that only the one that is clicked makes it into the POST. As such, you can simply check for the presence of one key or the other in the form data:

```
if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("Insert"))
    // do insert
if (Request.Form.ContainsKey("Edit"))
    // do edit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answear it helped me. Also thanks for spending your time on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a property `string ActionType` to your `ReklamaceMode` model.

Then change your HTML to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyMainView", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ....
    <input id="Insert" name="ActionType" value="Insert" type="submit">
    <input id="Edit" name="ActionType" value="Edit" type="submit">
}
```

Now in your csharp code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save(int IdentifikaceZ, ReklamaceModel model)
{
    // check model.ActionType, it will be either Insert or Edit
}
```

Comment: I cannot add string Action type to my model because its reading from db and it doesnt know column actiontype so it throws me an eror that Action type is now valid column but thanks for answer

Comment: You should never use your DB entities (models) in controllers! Create a DTO and use it in the request, then do your logic after mapping it.

Answer (score 0):

Add and update operations can be handled with one form and one method as well.

Add `id` as hidden form control, for existing records this field will have a value which is the relevant record id. For new records the value will be 0 by default (assuming id type is int).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyMainView", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ....

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

on the backend check for the `id` value, if it is > 0 then you trigger update, otherwise it is a new record.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save(int IdentifikaceZ, ReklamaceModel model)
{
   if(model.Id > 0)
       _db.Update(model);
   else
       _db.Add(model);

    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("MyMainView");
}
```

That was a simplified implementation, in a real life project you need to do more control over the model before adding/updating. For example it is recommended to use an input model then bind the values to the db model...

if ou still need to use multiple submit buttons in one form to target different backend actions see [Multiple Submit Buttons](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/MultipleSubmit) for standard form and ajax forms as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is smart way to do it. Thanks for spending your time on this problem. Also thanks for link. It helped me so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do like this:::

```
 <form method="post" asp-controller="Home">
<a id="Insert" name="Insert" value="Insert" type="submit" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-DeleteID="@model.DeleteID"/>
 <a id="Edit" name="Edit" value="Edit" type="submit" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-DeleteID="@model.EditID"/>
</form>

[HttpPost] public IActionResult Delete(int id) {

}

[HttpPost] public IActionResult Edit(int id) {

}
```